# Representing coordinates in javascript, and accessing elements in constant time

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I have a tree structure.

```
             root(0,0)
               /  \
              /    \
             /      \
         A(-1,1)   B(1,1)
           / \      / \
          /   \    /   \
         /     \        \  
     C(-2,2)  D(0,2)   E(2,2)
```

and **JSON**:

```
{
  "root": object, // Node at coordinate (0,0)
  "A": object, // Node at coordinate (-1,-1)
  "B": object, // Node at coordinate (1,1)
  "C": object, // Node at coordinate (-2,-2)
  "D": object, // Node at coordinate (0, 2)
  "E": object, // Node at coordinate (2,2)
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to maintain a matrix (2D Array) of coordinates that stores node name in a cell.

For example, a query like `matrix[0][0]` should yield `root`, `matrix[0][2]` should yield `D` and `matrix[-2][2]`, if possible at all should yield `C`.
This will let me access the element in constant time given x and y coordinates.

---

**Attempt**:

```
var matrix = new Array([]);
matrix[x][y] = nodeName; // nodeName is keys: "root", "A", "B" etc.
```

However, when x is a negative value I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined`

How can I define coordinate system in javascript using arrays or any other means?

Comment: why has **D** not a negative first *index*? do you have only two children of every node?

Comment: A node can have arbitrary number of children. Eg, if it has two children, one child renders to the left with x value 1 less than the parent and other child renders to the right with x value one greater than that of parent. In case of three children the middle child renders with x value exactly same as that of its parent.

Comment: You should be using plain objects, not arrays. Arrays have non-negative indexes.

Comment: does the index have a meaning? wouldn't it be better to have the level first? maybe you add a use case for it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Are saying `matrix[level][negative_x_value]` would be legal?

Comment: it is more a semantic approach. and yes, you could use negative indices as keys for arrays, but this items are not used for other special array methods, like `slice`. these properties are just normal properties of an object and they are not working for making jsons. i don't understand, why use use a coordinate system (kind of) for a tree structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Arrays, which are not meant for use with negative indices like this, I would use a look-up object.

Assuming that x and y are always numbers, here is one potential solution.

```js
var lookupTable = {};

function setElement(x, y, value) {
  lookupTable[x +"," + y] = value;
}

function getElement(x, y) {
  return lookupTable[x +"," + y];
}
```